# How to use soft assertions in Mockito?

Tags: mockito, assertion, verify, errorcollector

I know that we can use [`ErrorCollector`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/ErrorCollector.html) or [soft assertions](https://automationrhapsody.com/soft-assertions-not-fail-junit-test/) (AssertJ or TestNG) that do not fail a unit test immediately.

How they can be used with Mockito assertions? Or if they can't, does Mockito provide any alternatives?

---

#### Code sample

```
verify(mock).isMethod1();
verify(mock, times(1)).callMethod2(any(StringBuilder.class));
verify(mock, never()).callMethod3(any(StringBuilder.class));
verify(mock, never()).callMethod4(any(String.class));
```

#### Problem

In this snippet of code if a verification will fail, then the test will fail which will abort the remaining `verify` statements (it may require multiple test runs until all the failures from this unit test are revealed, which is time-consuming).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Mockito 2.1.0 you can use [VerificationCollector](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.9/org/mockito/junit/VerificationCollector.html) rule in order to collect multiple verification failures and report at once.

#### Example

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnit;
import org.mockito.junit.VerificationCollector;

// ...

    @Rule
    public final VerificationCollector collector = MockitoJUnit.collector();


    @Test
    public void givenXWhenYThenZ() throws Exception {
        // ...
        verify(mock).isMethod1();
        verify(mock, times(1)).callMethod2(any(StringBuilder.class));
        verify(mock, never()).callMethod3(any(StringBuilder.class));
        verify(mock, never()).callMethod4(any(String.class));
    }
```

#### Known issues

This rule cannot be used with [`ErrorCollector`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/ErrorCollector.html) rule in the same test method. In separate tests it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Using Soft assertions you could do :

```java
softly.assertThatThrownBy(() -> verify(mock).isMethod1()).doesNotThrowAnyException();
softly.assertThatThrownBy(() -> verify(mock, times(1)).callMethod2(any(StringBuilder.class))).doesNotThrowAnyException();
softly.assertThatThrownBy(() -> verify(mock, never()).callMethod3(any(StringBuilder.class))).doesNotThrowAnyException();
softly.assertThatThrownBy(() -> verify(mock, never()).callMethod4(anyString())).doesNotThrowAnyException();
```

If one or more of your mockito assertions fail, it will trigger an exception, and softAssertion will do the reporting job.

Comment: In Mockito 2, I had to use `softly.assertThatCode` instead for this to work.