# Is mockito support something like verificationCollector for TestNG, as it does for Junit?

Tags: java, mockito, verify

I need to use Mockito lazy verification, in order for Mockito to run ALL verifies, instead of stop on the 1st failed one.

I'm using TestNG and not JUnit.

Therefore I cannot use VerificationCollector since it's for Junit.

I need to have a similar solution for TestNG.

Please be elaborate when answering

Comment: Just wondering: why do you want to accumulate errors? The fact that it is possible to do so ... doesn't mean one should do it. The purpose of unit tests is to fail quickly and point you at errors. Far too often, later errors ... are caused by earlier errors anyway...

Comment: @GhostCat - I want to accumulate errors since I want to see ALL errors in a certain run. I don't want to run, fail on 1 test, then run again, fail on another and so on. I want to have the full picture from the first run and know the full status of my unit tests from the first run. And also - it's wrong to assume dependencies between all tests. I have very little such dependencies.

Comment: Sure, but as said: that can *quickly* lead to wasting time on the other end: by closely looking at errors ... that are a result of something that another test case already found. And well, I am not sure if I understand: JUnit at least will still run all tests, and in the end, there is a list with test classes (and test methods inside) that  failed. One page tells you which test classes failed, and then you can see for each which methods are affected. Doesnt testng have something like that?

Comment: @GhostCat - answering your last question - when using Mockito - the default behavior is to fail-fast, therefore - NO, no such report is generated since the rest of the verification part in the code is not reached.

Comment: I dont understand. Mockito fails a single  **testcase**.  A test suite is typically made up of many test classes, that contain many testcases. Are you telling me that testng stops completely when it runs into a first failing testcase?

Comment: @GhostCat: I think what the TO wants to express, is that he wishes to call verify multiple times in the same testcase without immediatley failing said testcase. What you are talking about is something different.  Check https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.9/org/mockito/junit/VerificationCollector.html

Comment: @second - thank you. That's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this answer ([How to continue execution when Assertion is failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402412/how-to-continue-execution-when-assertion-is-failed)) is not completly out of date,
you should be able to solve you issue by using soft assertions.

Edit:
But this post suggest that the VerificationCollector could be used as well, just with certain limitations. (But its not very clear from the answer wether it talks about testNG or not. If that does not work take a look at the not accepted answer.)

[How to use soft assertions in Mockito?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53694359/how-to-use-soft-assertions-in-mockito)